# HTML Layout, frames?

Tags: html, frames

It has been a while since I have developed a web site so I am asking for advice.

I am developing using asp.net mvc.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/t/2jr8r.jpg

The image in the link above is the basic layout for a web site. It is a portal type application. The blue part contains the user details, the black part contains links that when clicked will be displayed in the white part. In the white part I want to be able to trigger pop up windows if needed.

My question is what is the best way to separate the areas (black, blue, white)? Back in the day we would have used frames, what is the accepted way these days?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently most people use `div` tags.  You can make this kind of layout very easily today, [here's a fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/aufrT/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="header">
        header
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="sidebar">
            sidebar
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            main content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#page-wrap {
    width: 960px;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

#content {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
    background: black;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 400px;
}

#main {
    background: white;
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 760px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Be careful about "divitis". A HTML document should be semantic and not everything should be a `<div>` element.

Comment: @Dai: I assume you're referring to using the HTML5 tags instead?  I would offer this as a solution, however, it requires the use of a Javascript shim to work in older versions of Internet Explorer.  And I figured I could make up for the lack of "description" by at least giving a proper ID to each `div` element.

Comment: Yes, but there are other elements you can style without `<div>` wrappers, such as `<h1>` and `<ul>`.

Comment: Well sure, but I would never suggest using either of those tags for a website's main layout... not to mention that would have a pretty heavy impact on your SEO.  `div` tags are definitely correct here.